# Using custom controls in Visual Studio 2010 Designer

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am extending out controls to contain various properties as they are needed.  I want to know if it is possible to create a custom control but still use it in the Designer because they are used in various layouts which are nested; therefor hard to manage programtically.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible, but the problems start when you want to make user controls containing other controls that have nested objects (for example: a user control containing a DataGridView control that has a nested collection of columns).

In such a scenario I would advise you to serialize some simplified custom object (i.e. MyDataGridViewInitializer) in your user control from which a complex child control (i.e. DataGridView) will be initialized, as serializing such complex controls directly is a uphill battle.

Hope this helps.

This should get you started:

[Customizing Code Generation in the .NET Framework Visual Designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx)

[Creating Custom Controls-Providing Design Time Support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9667/Creating-Custom-Controls-Providing-Design-Time-Sup)